# Replacing Sketchup 8 API with deprecated version bundled with 2013 SDK - doesn't build in XCode

Tags: sdk, deprecated, sketchup

We have a project in which we use the SketchUp 8 C++ API to extract information from a SketchUp file.  We have been told by a SketchUp team member that the deprecated C++ frameworks bundled with the SketchUp 2013 SDK can be used instead to read SKP 2013 files using the deprecated C++ API.  This isn't working out of the box, and it's unclear what I'm doing wrong.  I'm posting my question on stackoverflow in case it's useful to others.

I'm building my project using XCode 3.2.2, on Mountain Lion, building to a base SDK of OS 10.5 i386.

I removed my XCode project's SketchUp.framework and SketchUpReader.framework, and added those included in the SKP 2013 SDK's deprecated/SkpReader/Binaries/Mac/ folder.  Doing a "Clean all targets" and Build produces thousands of errors.  Some examples:

```
.../SketchUpReader.framework/Headers/Variant.h:79: error: multiple definition of 'enum VARENUM'


.../SketchUpReader.framework/Headers/windef.h:217: error: variable or field 'Sleep' declared void

.../SketchUpReader.framework/Headers/comptr.h:17: error: redefinition of 'class _NoAddRefReleaseOnCComPtr<T>'
```

Most of the errors are of this form - something has a previous definition.

My first thought was that it was still including the old version of the C++ frameworks from somewhere, and the new and old were conflicting, but I don't see any other reference to sketchup frameworks in the Xcode project's list of frameworks, or in /Library/Frameworks.

I'm not terribly versed in building C++ projects or in using XCode, so this could be a naive question all around, but if anyone knows offhand what's going on here I'd appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, we've discovered what the issue is with the deprecated frameworks in SketchUpReader and are working on a solution. I'll post again when we've updated the SDK--it shouldn't be long.

Thanks for your patience!

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you patience on this.  We've just released a new SDK that should resolve the build issues with the deprecated SketchUpReader.framework.  You can go here to get that update: http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/sdk_start.html.  There's a new sample project now in the deprecated SDK called SkpStats that links with the framework that shows how to use it.

I expect all will be good now, but please let me know if you have any other issues with the new release.

Paul